# How to MIGRATE ANSI/MBCS Resources for Visual Studio 2019 C++ MFC project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2019, mbcs

I have an old VS2008 based MFC project.  We need to stick with ANSI/MBCS based characters - Wide Characters are not utilized.

However, it *appears* the Resource Editor .RC file output encoding is UNICODE (wide characters).

What is the proper procedure for MIGRATING ANSI based Resource Editor Resources (dialogs, strings, menus) from VS2008 TO Visual Studio 2019 C++ MFC Project, and be able to utilize the Resource EDITOR, not just the Resource COMPILER?

EDIT: This [MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-library-versions?view=msvc-160) talks about tweaking Project properties to support ANSI/MBCS (vs. Wide) characters, but no discussion on the Resource Editor.  My question is about the Visual Studio 2019 RESOURCE EDITOR (and implicitly the RESOURCE COMPILER where the Resource Editor would add the proper #pragma's to the .RC file mentioned in the comments).  The Resource Editor needs to be ANSI/MBCS capable, but when I change the project settings, the Resource Editor still generates UTF-16 Unicode files.

Is there a way to get VS 2019's Resource **Editor** to support ANSI/MBCS?

Comment: i've never heard of there being two types of resources. Does it not just work?

Comment: [Old New Thing - June 7th, 2019](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569) _"...To avoid this problem, the Resource Compiler lets you declare the code page in which the subsequent lines should be interpreted. ..."_

Comment: @user253751 That's a possibility.  It may "just work", it could be the Resource COMPILER translates them from the UNICODE Source to the ANSI/MBCS - which is perfectly acceptable answer (I was thinking it could be done at RUNTIME - but COMPILE is OBVIOUSLY better)

Comment: At least the normally, you simply don't worry about it. You create some resources, and build for either mbcs or Unicode, and it just works without your taking any further action.

Comment: I am migrating an old ANSI/MBCS project to VS-2019.  The old RC file is ASCII - the VS 2019 Resource editor spits out Unicode .rc files, hence the reason for my question.

Comment: [all 32-bit dialog resources have unicode strings](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040621-00/?p=38793). You could go back to Windows 3.1, I suppose.